# What does this assembly instruction do?

Tags: assembly, c

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%eax
mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%edx
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
mov    %edx,(%rax)
mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
mov    %edx,(%rax)
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%edx
mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
mov    (%rax),%eax
add    %edx,%eax
pop    %rbp
retq
```

I am just looking for someone to confirm my thinking, what I am seeing happen is that parameter 1 is taken and put 18 below rbp and parameter two is taken and put 20 below rbp and then it seems to me that the parameters are set to each other as in x=y and y=x however at the very end the second parameter is set to rax and then added to edx which i believe is the first parameter and then returned. Is this correct or am i way off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that seems correct. The equivalent C code would look something like:

```
int func(int *arg1, int *arg2)
{
    int temp = *arg1;
    *arg1 = *arg2;
    *arg2 = temp;
    return *arg1 + *arg2;
}
```

The use of stack-based storage indexed off of `rbp` is what we called [local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). We can give each use a name to make it easier to see what is going on. Let's call the value at `rbp-0x18` local_arg1, `rbp-0x20` local_arg2 and `rbp-0x4` local_temp. By [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), `rdi` is the first argument to the function and `rsi` is the second.

Adding comments where pointer dereferencing is occurring, the disassembly is then

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp         
mov    %rdi,local_arg1
mov    %rsi,local_arg2
mov    local_arg1,%rax
mov    (%rax),%eax        ; dereference the pointer i.e. eax = *arg1
mov    %eax,local_temp
mov    local_arg2,%rax
mov    (%rax),%edx        ; edx = *arg2
mov    local_arg1,%rax
mov    %edx,(%rax)        ; *arg1 = edx
mov    local_arg2,%rax
mov    local_temp,%edx
mov    %edx,(%rax)        ; *arg2 = edx
mov    local_arg1,%rax
mov    (%rax),%edx        ; edx = *arg1
mov    local_arg2,%rax
mov    (%rax),%eax        ; eax = *arg2
add    %edx,%eax
pop    %rbp
retq
```

Comment: awesome how do you know they are pointers and not just ints?

Comment: is it because of the (%rbp) vs %rbp stating value of ?

Comment: I updated the answer to better explain that.

Comment: How did you decompiled your c code to assembly and vise-versa?

Comment: No tool, I just created the C code from my experience of what compilers generate and the disassembly is very straightforward so it's pretty easy to what is going on. Any good decompiler tool should generate something similar to what I put down though.